# Change the icon of one specific folder in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

How to change the icon of one specific folder in Windows 8? I want to customize some folders' icons.

Comment: @JanDoggen LMGTFY links are considered quite rude. Why not take what the video shows and phrase it as a proper answer? That'd be the better course of action, as YouTube videos might go offline and are not a very easily accessible source of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following tutorial provided useful when I wanted to do something similar.

> First, open Windows Explorer, which defaults to the Libraries view.
>   Here, if you right-click a default library and choose Properties,
>   you'll see that there are a few changes from the same dialog in
>   Windows 7.

[image]

> First, the Include a folder button has been renamed to Add. A new
>   button, called Set public save location, allows you to set a new
>   libraries options, for a public save location. (In Windows 7,  you
>   could only set the current user's save location.) And finally, there's
>   a new Change library icon option, though that's grayed out for default
>   libraries like Documents.
>
> Check the properties sheet for custom library, however, and that
>   option is now available.

[image]

> To change the icon, click the Change library icon button. This will
>   display the Change Icon dialog, which will by default show a great
>   collection of new and old Windows icons. (Some actually date back to
>   Windows 95.) Select the icon you want and click OK.

[image]

> Now, your custom library has a new icon.

[image]

> **Note:** Power users will typically hide the humongous Explorer ribbon in Windows 8, but if you prefer to use that, this option is
>   available from the ribbon as well. Simply select the library icon
>   you'd like to change and then select Change icon from the ribbon.

[image]

[Windows 8 Secrets: Changing a Custom Library Icon Oct 1 2011 Paul Thurrott](http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-8-secrets-changing-custom-library-icon)